# "have a feeling that" vs. "have the feeling that"

Tags: articles

Tell me please if can use any article in the following sentences.

> I have **a** feeling that Kate is angry with me.
>
> I have **the** feeling that Kate is angry with me.

I am not sure which article I should use. Are both sentences correct, if not, then which and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, with only a subtle difference in nuance.  As usual, *a* is vague and unspecified, while *the* indicates more certainty.

> I have **a feeling** we are going to be late (= I'm not sure but I think this will happen)
>
> I have **the feeling** we are going to be late (= I'm not sure but I'm fairly certain this will happen)

Since things like degree of anxiety and uncertainty vary from person to person, there's no way to say *exactly* what these mean in every situation.  You have to judge from the context, and what you know about the speaker.

This is the same for most similar nouns: *idea, belief, thought, sense, intention*, etc.

Related note:  Both *a* and *the* don't work with *feeling* in every context. For example:

> (✔) I have **a bad feeling** about this.
>   (✖) I have **the bad feeling** about this.

If you want to use *the*, then you have to be specific:

> I have the bad feeling (that) **Kate is angry with me**.